# How to break node path without distorting the object?

Tags: inkscape, vector

Inkscape completely distorts the object when a path between selected nodes is broken.

How to avoid this?

```
                           ***  Updated Question  ***
```

The visualize nodes tool shows continuity between the selected and the  neighbouring nodes.Still there is complete distortion (ie unconnected nodes right upto the leg are being distorted)on using break nodes tool .

In such a case ,how to split an object into parts ?

[image: node number]

[image]

Comment: That isn't distortion. You have opened the path, so it's no longer a closed path, and now the fill is broken. This is expected behaviour. What are you actually trying to achieve? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question.Isn't there any way to split a object(with perfect node continuity) without causing complete distortion?

Comment: There is no distortion. The nodes are not moving. You've opened a closed path, and so now you've broken the fill. This is user error.  Without knowing what you are ACTUALLY trying to achieve, I can't really answer this question. Why are you trying to split up a path? What are you trying to achieve by doing so?  At the moment what you are asking is like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your path is more complex than you assume. You didn't open the path between adjacent nodes. Put option Show Path Outline =ON in the info panel or insert temporarily a stroke. Show outline happens if the node tool is selected.

There's also extension Visualize Path > Node numbers to show the order. Use it only as preview.

If this guess was right and you for some reason must break the path you must bite the bullet and redraw a simpler version or move the nodes one by one to a simpler order.

Another explanation is that you broke 2 separate shapes at the same time.

ADD:

As a method how to divide a single closed path I suggest you to draw with the pen the division line or curve. Select the shape to be divided and the divider. Goto Path > Division. The drawn divider vanishes. Here's an example in Inkscape version 1.0

[image]

**Cut Path** can also be used. It splits the selected path below in every crossing. The result is an open curve or several open curves.